# Searching & retrieving filenames from an FTP site using wininet.dll api

Tags: vb6, ftp, wininet

I've been trying to use the wininet.dll api to search an ftp site for matching files but it's not working for some reason.
Here's the method i've been using.

```
Private Sub DoStuff()
     Dim hConnection As Long, hOpen As Long, sOrgPath As String, lRes As Long
     Dim scUserAgent$

    scUserAgent$ = "vb wininet"
    hOpen = InternetOpen(scUserAgent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
    hConnection = InternetConnect(hOpen, mServer$, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, mUserid$, mPassword$, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0)

    ''//set the current directory to 'root/testdir/testdir2'
    FtpSetCurrentDirectory hConnection, "testdir/testdir2"

    ReDim matchingFiles$(1)
    Call SearchForFiles(hConnection, ".txt", matchingFiles$)


    ''//Close the connections
    InternetCloseHandle hConnection
    InternetCloseHandle hOpen
End Sub
```

Here is the SearchForFiles function

```
Public Sub SearchForFiles(hConnection As Long, fileExtension$, matchingFiles$())
    Dim pData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, hFind As Long, lRet As Long
    Dim i%

    ReDim matchingFiles$(1)

    i% = 1

    ''//create a buffer
    pData.cFileName = String(MAX_PATH, 0)
    ''//find the first file
    hFind = FtpFindFirstFile(hConnection, "*." + fileExtension$, pData, 0, 0)

    ''//if there is no file, then exit sub

    If hFind = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ''//show the filename

    matchingFiles$(i%) = Left(pData.cFileName, InStr(1, pData.cFileName, String(1, 0), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)

    Do
        i% = i% + 1
        ''//create a buffer
        pData.cFileName = String(MAX_PATH, 0)
        ''//find the next file
        lRet = InternetFindNextFile(hFind, pData)
        ''//if there is no next file, exit do
        If lRet = 0 Then Exit Do
        ''//show the filename
        ReDim Preserve matchingFiles$(UBound(matchingFiles) + 1)
        matchingFiles$(i%) = Left(pData.cFileName, InStr(1, pData.cFileName, String(1, 0), vbBinaryCompare) - 1)

    Loop
    ''//close the search handle
    InternetCloseHandle hFind
End Sub
```

All i keep getting is "." and ".." for the files being returned from the SearchForFiles function. Am i doing something incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Fix my code!

What have you tried? WHERE does it break? Can you step through it?

Comment: It doesn't break. It's just that it never reads the matching .txt files sitting on the FTP site under the directory /root/testdir/testdir2/

Comment: When submitting vb code next time, be aware that the syntax highlighting doesn't like apostrophe's for comment.  I took the liberty to change all comment `'comment` to `''//`, which is understood better (and won't break your code either)

Comment: thanks xtofl! I'll remember that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `".txt"` you provide as  `fileExtension$` argument to the `SearchForFiles` routine is concatenated as is to the `"*."` pattern, yielding `"*..txt"`.  Maybe that's what bothers your program?  I do wonder why "." and ".." are found using this pattern, though...